# QueryDsl does not generate q-classes for @Entity classes of git submodules

Tags: java, git-submodules, querydsl

I have a java project (spring boot) with git submodules. I've added QueryDsl to my project but it generates q-classes only for @Entity classes of main project, not for @Entity classes of submodules.

What should I do to fix it?

p.s. Spring Data works well, all @Entity classes are available to use.

Comment: Did you configure QueryDsl in the pom of the submodule? That worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have pom in submodule. We use that submodule just as package of POJOs shared between microservices.

Comment: Then, can you add more details about the project structure and your pom in the main question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `package-info.java` file to your own project, that references the classes from the child project in `@QueryEntities`:

```java
@QueryEntities({
        BlobEntity.class
})
package com.pallasathenagroup.querydsl;

import com.blazebit.persistence.testsuite.entity.BlobEntity;
import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities;
```

Comment: That solves the issue, thank You. Now I just need to get to understand what it does...

Comment: It allows QueryDSL to find the class to generate a metamodel for during annotation processing (APT) on your projects sources.